# How do I use "Ctrl" key and "V" in Windows 10 to "Paste" to a directory selected with the mouse instead of the current directory?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

How do I use "Ctrl" key and "V" in Windows 10 to "Paste" to a directory selected with the mouse instead of the current directory?

I want to change the behavior to the same as the context menu "Paste".

---

Added the concrete behavior I expect

The whole idea of what I want to do is as follows.
Cut and paste "K:\a.jpg" and "K:\b.jpg" into "L:\p\c

**1. Selecting multiple image files**

In drive K, select "a.jpg" and "b.jpg" with the mouse.

**2. Hold down the "Ctrl" key and press "X" to cut.**

In Drive K, with "a.jpg" and "b.jpg" selected with the mouse, hold down the "Ctrl" key and press "X".

**3. Move to the target directory for pasting**

While moving to the "p" directory directly under the L drive, select the "c" directory below it with the mouse.
The current directory is the "p" directory at this point.

**4. Hold down the "Ctrl" key and press "V" to paste.**

"a.jpg" and "b.jpg" will be pasted into the current "p" directory.

**I would like to change this behavior to "the same behavior as context menu pasting".**
Specifically, I want to paste "a.jpg" and "b.jpg" into the "c" directory selected with the mouse using the power of AutoHotkey.

Comment: I want to change the behavior outside of the tree view.

Comment: I found out that I could not do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's possible using AutoHotKey, if you're interested. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I would love to try it. How can I do it? Or is there a URL that might be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will for Explorer get a file or folder
from the clipboard and copy it to the currently selected folder in
Explorer. If the clipboard contains a folder, the *contents* of the
folder are copied.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe explorer.exe          ; only for explorer

^v::                                        ; handle ctrl-v
selected = % Explorer_GetSelection()        ; get currently selected item in explorer as source ;*[test]
FileGetAttrib, attrselected, %selected%     ; get attributes of selected item
; check if source & target exist, are not equal, and target is a folder
if selected and clipboard and selected != clipboard and InStr("%attrselected%", "D")
{
  Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
    FileCopy, %A_LoopField%, %selected%     ; copy source to target
}


Explorer_GetSelection() {
   WinGetClass, winClass, % "ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A")
   if !(winClass ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass")
      Return
   for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
      if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (oShellFolderView := window.document)
         break
   for item in oShellFolderView.SelectedItems
      result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.path
   if !result
      result := oShellFolderView.Folder.Self.Path
   Return result
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I tried, but it did not work as expected.Added specific expected behavior to the text

Comment: Ah, yes, multiple selected items added.

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you.
 This is my first time using AutoHotkey and it is great.