# How can I prevent the 0x80004005 error from appearing when I run AutoHotkey code?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, autohotkey

```
  #IfWinActive, ahk_exe explorer.exe          ; only for explorer
    
    ^sc07B::
    selected = % Explorer_GetSelection()        ; get currently selected item in explorer as source ;*[test]
    FileGetAttrib, attrselected, %selected%     ; get attributes of selected item
    ; check if source & target exist, are not equal, and target is a folder
    if selected and clipboard and selected != clipboard and InStr("%attrselected%", "D")
    {
      Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
        FileMove, %A_LoopField%, %selected% 
    }
    
    
    Explorer_GetSelection() {
       WinGetClass, winClass, % "ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A")
       if !(winClass ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass")
          Return
       for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
          if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (oShellFolderView := window.document)
             break
       for item in oShellFolderView.SelectedItems
          result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.path
       if !result
          result := oShellFolderView.Folder.Self.Path
       Return result
    }
```

When the above code is executed, error 0x80004005 is displayed.

```
Error:0x80004005
Source:(null)
Description:(null)
HelpFile:(null)
HelpContext:(null)

Specifically:HWND
```

Then press Y and it works as expected.

Q1. How can I prevent the 0x80004005 error from being displayed?

Q2.Why didn't this error appear yesterday, but today it does?

The above code is a partial modification of "[How do I use "Ctrl" key and "V" in Windows 10 to "Paste" to a directory selected with the mouse instead of the current directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1716786/how-do-i-use-ctrl-key-and-v-in-windows-10-to-paste-to-a-directory-selected)".

^v:: → ^sc07B::

FileCopy → FileMove

---

Postscript.

Exceptions may occur in the following areas (exceptions may not occur).
I would like to check the exception content e but it is not displayed. Is there any way to modify the code?

```
Try     ; Attempts to execute code.
{
   for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
      if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (oShellFolderView := window.document)
         break
}
Catch e     ; Handles the first error/exception raised by the block above.
{
    MsgBox, An exception was thrown!`nSpecifically: %e%
    Exit
}
```

The results of the
MsgBox, An exception was thrown!`nSpecifically: %hWnd%

> 0x421d12

The results of the
MsgBox, An exception was thrown!`nSpecifically: %window.HWND%

> The following variable name contains an illegal character
> "window.HWND"

Answer (score 1):

can't tell the exact way to implement it in this case, but guess it should be helpful: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Try.htm

Comment: The result of the try catch test was added to the main text.

Answer (score -1):

i'm Sage7, i had experienced similar issue in my first Com test today.
and i have finally solved it.

it seems caused by ComObjCreate or autohotkey internally 32bit
the limit of iExploer32.exe, they can't be loaded exceeding total 4GB memory.
manage not to access too many iExploer32 (or windows)

to solve, kill process tree in most top parent iExploer.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).